# Implementation of a singly linked list data structure in C

Tags: c

This is a follow-up to the previous question located at [Singly linked list implementation in pure C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140733/singly-linked-list-implementation-in-pure-c)
Any suggestions on design and optimization are highly appreciated

LINKEDLIST.H

```
#ifndef NYO_LINKED_LIST
#define NYO_LINKED_LIST

#include "stdbool.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct LinkedList {
    Node *head, *tail;
    int length;
} LinkedList;

void LinkedList_Swap(int*,int*);
void LinkedList_Init(LinkedList*);
void LinkedList_Add(LinkedList*, Node*);
Node* createNode(int);
void LinkedList_Show(LinkedList*);
void LinkedList_PushFront(LinkedList*, Node*);
int LinkedList_GetDataAt(LinkedList*,int);
Node *getNode(LinkedList*,int);
void LinkedList_DeleteLast(LinkedList*);
bool LinkedList_Found(LinkedList*,int);
void LinkedList_Reverse(LinkedList*);
void LinkedList_Clear(LinkedList*);
void LinkedList_InsertAt(LinkedList*,int,int);
void LinkedList_DeleteAt(LinkedList*,int);
void LinkedList_Free(LinkedList*);

#endif
```

LINKEDLIST.c

```
#include "C:\Users\___\Desktop\workspace\linkedList.h"
#define DEBUG
#undef DEBUG

void LinkedList_Swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

void LinkedList_Init(LinkedList *list)
{
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = list->head;
    list->length = 0;
}

void LinkedList_Add(LinkedList *list, Node* node)
{
    if(list->head!=NULL)
    {
        list->tail->next = (struct Node*)node;
        list->tail = node;
    }
    else
    {
        list->head = node;
        list->tail = list->head;
    }
    ++list->length;
}

Node* createNode(int data)
{
    Node *tmp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next = NULL;
    return tmp;
}

void LinkedList_Show(LinkedList *list)
{
    Node *tmp = list->head;
    while(tmp != NULL)
    {
        printf("[%d]\n",tmp->data);
        tmp = (Node*)tmp->next;
    }

}

void LinkedList_PushFront(LinkedList *list, Node* node)
{
    node->next = (struct Node*)list->head;
    if(list->head!=NULL)
    {
        list->head = node;
    }
    else
    {

        list->head = node;
        list->tail = list->head;
    }
    ++list->length;
}
int LinkedList_GetDataAt(LinkedList *list, int index)
{
    Node *tmp = list->head;
    int count = 0;
    if(index >= 0 && index < list->length)
    {
        while(tmp!=NULL)
        {
            if(count == index) return tmp->data;
            ++count;
            tmp = (Node*)tmp->next;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

Node *getNode(LinkedList *list, int index)
{

    Node *tmp = list->head;
    int count = 0;
    if(index >= 0 && index < list->length)
    {
        while(tmp!=NULL)
        {
            if(count == index) return tmp;
            ++count;
            tmp = (Node*)tmp->next;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void LinkedList_DeleteLast(LinkedList *list)
{

    Node *tmp = list->head;
    int i;
    Node *beforeLast;
    if(list->length>0)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < list->length; ++i)
        {

            if(i == list->length-2)
            {
                beforeLast = tmp;

            }
            if(tmp!=NULL)
            {
                tmp =(Node*) tmp->next;
            }


        }

        free(beforeLast->next);
        beforeLast->next = NULL;
        list->tail = beforeLast;
    }
    else
    {
        free(list->head);
        LinkedList_Init(list);
    }
    if(list->length>0)
    {
        --list->length;
    }
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Actual length -> [%d]\n",list->length);
#endif 
}

bool LinkedList_Found(LinkedList *list, int toFind)
{
    Node *tmp = list->head;
    while(tmp!=NULL)
    {
        if(toFind==tmp->data) return true;
        tmp = (Node*)tmp->next;
    }
    return false;
}
void LinkedList_Reverse(LinkedList *list)
{
    int len, i;
    for (i = 0, len = list->length-1; i < len; ++i, --len)
    {
        LinkedList_Swap((int*)getNode(list,i), (int*)getNode(list,len));
    }

}

void LinkedList_InsertAt(LinkedList *list, int index, int data)
{

    Node *tmp = list->head;
    Node *newNode = createNode(data);
    Node *left, *right;
    int count = 0;

    if(index == 0)  LinkedList_PushFront(list,createNode(data));

    else if (index == list->length-1) LinkedList_Add(list,createNode(data));

    else if(index > 0 && index < list->length)
    {
        {
            while(tmp!=NULL)
            {
                left = tmp;
                right = tmp->next;
                if(count == index - 1)
                {
                    left->next = newNode;
                    newNode->next = right;
                    ++list->length;
                    break;

                }
                ++count;
                tmp = (Node*)tmp->next;
            }

        }

    }
}

void LinkedList_DeleteAt(LinkedList *list, int index)
{

    Node *left, *right;
    Node *tmp = list->head;
    int count = 0;
    if(index > 0 && index < list->length-1)
    {

        while(tmp!=NULL)
        {

            left = tmp;
            right = tmp->next;
            if(count == index-1)
            {
#ifdef DEBUG
                printf("left -> %d right -> %d\n", left->data, right->data);
#endif
                left->next = right->next;
                break;
            }

            ++count;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        --list->length;

    }
    else if (index == list->length-1)
    {
        LinkedList_DeleteLast(list);
    }
    else
    {

        list->head = list->head->next;
        free(tmp);
        tmp = NULL;
    }
}
void LinkedList_Free(LinkedList *list){
    free(list);
    list = NULL;
}


void LinkedList_Clear(LinkedList *list)
{
    while(list->head!=NULL)
    {
        LinkedList_DeleteAt(list,0);
    }
}
```

MAIN.C

```
#include "C:\Users\___\Desktop\workspace\linkedList.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    LinkedList *list = (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));

    LinkedList_Init(list);
    LinkedList_Add(list,createNode(1));
    LinkedList_Add(list,createNode(2));
    LinkedList_Add(list,createNode(3));
    LinkedList_Add(list,createNode(4));
    LinkedList_DeleteAt(list,1);
    LinkedList_Reverse(list);
    LinkedList_Show(list);
    LinkedList_Clear(list);

    LinkedList_Free(list);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use \\ instead of \ in your path

Comment: whats with the define and undef of DEBUG?

Comment: it was done for debugging purposes

Comment: Since you've already done a follow up to this question, could you please accept one of the answers here.

Answer (score 2):

- **`LinkedList_Add`**

  Regardless of the initial state of the list, the newly added node becomes `tail`:

  ```
  {
      if (list->head == NULL) {
          list->head = node;
      } else {
          tail->next = node;
      }
      list->tail = node;
  }
  ```

  Same applies to `LinkedList_PushFront`: the node becomes `head` no matter what.

  ```
  {
      node->next = list->head;
      list->head = node;
      if (node->next == 0) {
          list->tail = node;
      }
  }
  ```
- **`LinkedList_DeleteLast`**

  is overly complicated. Treat a special case first:

  ```
      if (list->head->next == 0) {
          delete head and return
      }

      Node * current = list->head;
      // At this point you know for sure that current->next is valid.
      while (current->next != list->tail) {
          current = current->next;
      }
      delete_tail()
      current->next = NULL;
      list->tail = current;
  ```
- **`LinkedList_Reverse`**

  has a quadratic time complexity (due to the linear complexity of `getNode`). Instead of swapping data, consider reversing links in a single linear pass:

  ```
  Node * prev = current;
  Node * current = list->head;
  while (current) {
      Node * next = current->next;
      current->next = prev;
      prev = current;
      current = next;
  }
  ```
- __`LinkedList_DeleteAt`

  is buggy. First, if `index > list->length`, the final `else` is executed, removing a head. I don't think it is intended behaviour. Second, if the list has just one element (that is, becomes empty after deletion), `list->tail` is not adjusted and becomes a dangling pointer.
- **Misc**

  The cast in `tmp = (Node*)tmp->next;` is totally unnecessary.

  Use curly brackets consistently.

  Insert and delete better return `bool` to inform the user whether the action completed successfully (e.g. insertion happened) or not.

Comment: thanks for pointing out some of these errors, I'll fix them as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The function `LinkedList_Swap` should not be part of the API, since it doesn't take a parameter of type `LinkedList`.

The function `LinkedList_Show` should not be part of the API, since it is too specialized (it can only print to `stdout`).

The function `createNode` should be static, since it is only used in the same file.

The `#include` lines should not use absolute paths.

The function `LinkedList_Found` should be named `Find`, since all the other names are also in present tense.

Instead of a `while` loop, a `for` loop is more idiomatic, e.g.

```
for (Node *n = head; n != NULL; n = n->next) { … }
```